# UIFont doesn't set the correct font name when pointSize is 0

Tags: ios, uifont

Why does UIFont incorrectly print out the font name when the size is set to zero?
When I set the size to anything greater than zero, then the correct font name is output. Is there a particular reason behind this behavior or is this a true bug.

```
UIFont* f1 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:0];
NSLog(@"%@",f1);
UIFont* f2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:1];
NSLog(@"%@",f2);
```

Output:

```
<UICTFont: 0x7fb90c988e10> font-family: "Helvetica"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 0.00pt
<UICTFont: 0x7fad92177a90> font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Thin"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 1.00pt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/fontWithName:size:):

> *fontSize*  The size (in points) to which the font is scaled. This value must be greater than 0.0.

You are trying to implement behaviour which is not supported. An 'incorrect' result is to be expected.

Comment: That makes total sense since font sizes in the real world are unsigned numbers. It does seem strange to me that they would still give you a different font name. Why not just give the correct one? I guess that comes down to Apple's implementation, which I cannot see.

Comment: @s.ka, I would imagine it comes down to Helvetica being the  default system font before iOS7. Still lurking around to annoy you at _undef_ moments like this.